# How to define the database path for embedded JTA?

Tags: java, database, eclipselink, jta

How can I manually define the database path for an `EclipseLink JTA DB`?

```
<persistence>
    <persistence-unit name="myapp" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>jdbc/myapp</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-and-create-tables" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I'd like to use Squirrel Database tool to inspect the DB, therefore would like to specify the path...

Or is a JTA not ment to have a certain path, but just managed by the container in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define the JTA-datasource in the container, which is then responsible for placing the datasource at that location for the provider to lookup.  The jta-data-source tag just tells the provider what name to use to look it up with.

If you are not in a container, in JPA 2.0 you would use the javax.persistence.jdbc.url property to define the URL.  Prior to that you would use vendor specific properties such as "eclipselink.jdbc.url" to define the connection in a java SE environment.